# more swapping on RHEL8 than RHEL7?

Tags: linux, rhel, performance, swap, virtual-memory

we've been having a Linux application for quite some time (our journey started a decade ago with RHEL 4). We were recently running our app on RHEL 7.9 and are now moving to RHEL 8.4.

We've always being setting vm.swappiness to 1 in order to avoid swapping from occuring as much as possible while there is still lots of available memory (Gigs of pages in the page cache): yes we prefer eating page cache first :-)

This has always worked pretty well on RHEL 7.x: we've never seen swapping occuring while available memory was above 500MB or so. Our systems typically have between 16 and 64 GB of RAM.

On RHEL 8.4, I'm pretty sure I've witnessed several occurences of swapping occuring while there was plenty (a few Gigs) of available memory. This never happened in similar conditions on RHEL 7.

So I'd like to understand what has changed between RHEL 7 and RHEL 8 from the standpoint of swapping 'aggressiveness' or maybe where I should start to better characterize/troubleshoot/understand why this swapping decision is taken.

Would you guys have some knowledge/recommendations around how I can achieve this ?

Many thanks in advance.
++Cyrille

Comment: So if Linux needs some extra RAM, you are telling it to dispose of that read ahead memory its got. It can always be read from disk again. It depends what you use your memory for - on a file server you probably don't want swappiness=1. You need to do some monitoring of your swap under different conditions.

Comment: swappiness probably doesn't work like you think it does.   More precisely, the way you think swappiness works is probably wrong.  Most people have very faulty assumptions about what it does (and many people think any swapping at all is inherently bad, which is entirely wrong - swap thrashing is bad, swap usage is not).    There's a pretty good explanation at [What Is Swappiness on Linux? (and How to Change It)](https://www.howtogeek.com/449691/what-is-swapiness-on-linux-and-how-to-change-it/).   In most cases, you're better off just leaving it alone and letting the kernel do its job.

Comment: Hi @Jeremy Boden, this is not for a file server but more an in memory DB, so indeed, we prefer avoid swapping rather than promoting page cache.

Comment: Hi @cas, thanks for your comment. I totally understand the difference between a bit of swapping and swap thrashing. In our case, even a bit of swapping (while there is enough page cache to reclaim) has a visible impact on our in-memory DB server response time, hence why I'm trying to avoid any swapping. I'll probably end up deconfiguring the swap device.

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, the behavior we had detected has been confirmed as a bug by Red Hat ([Bugzilla 1990580](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1990580), which isn’t public).

Comment: Can you possibly reference this issue in something that isn't private/proprietary so that others can try to understand it?

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/8.7_release_notes/kernel_parameters_changes
see force_cgroup_v2_swappiness

Comment: I am seeing increased swapping irrespective of cgroupsv2, infact RHEL8 still defaults to cgroups v1 and it absolutely swaps more under identical workloads.

Answer (score 2):

We have same problem with swap, RHEL and MariaDB. Our temporary solution is downgrading kernel to old version from RHEL 8.0/8.1. This problem only appears with kernel from RHEL 8.2/8.3/8.4/8.5.

Kernel **without** problem: 4.18.0-80.el8 - 4.18.0-147.8.1.el8_1

Kernel **with** problem: 4.18.0-193.el8 - 4.18.0-348.12.2.el8_5 (and all new kernels like 5.4.x and 5.16.x from [elrepo.org](https://elrepo.org))

P.S: [Cyrille MAUCCI](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/480641/cyrille-maucci) can you share additional information (without sensitive data) from Red Hat Bugzilla issue which mentions in [your answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/680387/513053)?

> FWIW, the behavior we had detected has been confirmed as a bug by Red Hat ([Bugzilla 1990580](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1990580), which isn’t public).

So, for the moment, it looks like downgrading the kernel is the only workaround. Perhaps, this information can help me and other users.

Comment: Why is it not a really answer? Our systems worked on RHEL 7.6. Memory and swap consumption were well. Then, we migrated to RHEL 8.4 and we saw high memory and swap consumption. I spent two weeks for finding a solution or at least a workaround. And I found that we can downgrade kernel and that temporary (until we bring back a new kernel version) solves problem. Why not?

Comment: "You need to downgrade your kernel" is an answer. It is providing a workaround. Yes, it isn't a great solution, but it is the solution that Jiffs has found and which works for Jiff so this is an answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, the bugzilla ticket has just been marked as VERIFIED in kernel-4.18.0-361.el8
This kernel level is embedded in the (currently) latest available RHEL 8.6 beta.
We've not yet been able to verify it ourselves
++Cyrille

Comment: This might be better if (1) you made it an edit to your other answer, rather than trying to make it look like a separate answer, and (2) you could provide a (publically accessible) reference.   Also (3), it's been two years.   Can you update us on your experience?

Comment: 1. I'm sorry to have misedited in the first place.
2. The only 'publically accessible' ref I have is https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2023:0496 (c.f. HPE: Premature swapping with swappiness=0 while there’s still plenty of pagecache to be reclaimed. (BZ#2151634))
3. The errata fixed our pb.

Answer (score 1):

The version of the kernel you're running has changed - it's solely responsible for swapping. RHEL 7 uses kernel 3.10, RHEL 8 uses 4.18 - there's a ton of changes between them.

If you never run out of RAM, you could as well disable swapping altogether. I've been doing it for over a decade now because swapping leads to a very unpredictable behavior and responsiveness issues and more often than not doesn't really help.

Comment: Hello @artem, yes that's probably what we're gonna do, i.e. disable swapping. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to upgrade to RH 8.7, you will find a workaround here https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/9276#issuecomment-1256304197

Tested on various RHEL 8, from 8.2 to 8.6 : it works.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [link-only answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) are discouraged, as the link may become invalid or the linked content change. Please edit your answer to include at least a summary of the linked explanation.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/436915)